# NGINX RTMP Live Streaming Input/output error using on_publish to access external microservice

Tags: nginx, rtmp, live-streaming

Nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4000;
        application stream {
            live on;
            #exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/$name -codec copy -f flv rtmp://$name-live-encoder/play;
            on_publish http://<hostName>:<port>/auth/validate;
            exec ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/$name -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://live-${name}-udp-encoder-service.rtmp-live-test:3555;
        }
    }
}
```

Incoming RTMP stream : rtmp://host:port/stream/ksptv?secret=234rfghi4e

Microservice : http://HOSTNAME/auth/validate?name=ksptv&secret=234rfghi4e ==> will return 201 if the secret Key matches with channel or 403 if it doesnt match ..

when the RTMP is getting streamed , the stream is exited with I/O error
**input rtmp stream logs**

> rtmp://rtmpHOST/stream/qptv-ind1?secret=hYn4cyWW56WdAhLussHkUw==:
> Input/output error [AVIOContext @ 0x2291f00] Statistics: 199663 bytes
> read, 0 seeks

The on_publish is not processing or hitting the microservice when using as below

```
        on_publish http://<hostName>:<port>/auth/validate;
```

But when I implement on_publish with localhost/auth and have server block defined in nginx.conf with **location /auth {return 201}** , rtmp streaming is successful

Can you please help me to understand why on_publish is not working with external url/api.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?  I'm having a similar issue; although I'm suspecting it has to do with my kubernetes dns since I don't see my auth service being hit -- although I do see the 'on_publish' description in my logs.